# My application should be downloaded by particular countries only in Android? How can I do?

Tags: android

I have developed one application and i am going to publish it in the Android Market. But I need to specify, that some particular countries can only download my application. How can I do this..? Helping minds are appreciated. Please respond to this question as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Google has provided this option to select the countries in which your app can be purchased or downloaded. Here is a screenshot of it. You can select the countries easily by just enabling them. And this can be done during uploading your app to Android Market, that is Google Play.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When submitting your app in the Google Play Store you can select which countries the app is available. Under publishing options, pricing, then tick boxes for countries

Comment: Than q so much.. For your immediate response..!